# 403 Trying to Upload to Firebase Storage via Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am receiving the following error when attempting to upload a file to storage.

```
[ { domain: 'global',
   reason: 'forbidden',
   message: '<name>@<app>.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to <app>.appspot.com/temp.txt.' } ]
```

Here is how I am doing the upload

```
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceaccount.json')
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<app>.appspot.com"
})

const storage = admin.storage()
storage.bucket().upload('<my file path>')
```

My service account does have owner and storage admin access in IAM. So, my question is what am I doing wrong and/or what access do I need to give my service account to be able to upload files to Firebase Storage from Firebase Functions?

Comment: You should be able to upload to your default storage bucket using the default service account when you initialize with no args: `admin.initializeApp()`.  Does that work?

Comment: @DougStevenson That does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Doug Stevenson, what solved this for me was not specifying a service account and just using the default one.

```
admin.initializeApp()
```

Comment: In case if you would have several non-default buckets, you need to create those buckets manually in Firebase project console at first.
After that you would be able to write to those buckets easily.

PS If you still have troubles: I have "Storage Object Admin" in IAM section to Firebase admin service account